# Does the Immovable Object spell prevent damage to the targeted object?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage, objects

The [*immovable object*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/immovable-object) spell description says, in part (*Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*, p. 187):

> You touch an object that weighs no more than 10 pounds and cause it to become magically fixed in place. You and the creatures you designate when you cast this spell can move the object normally. [...]
>
> If the object is fixed in the air, it can hold up to 4,000 pounds of weight. [...]

Does the *immovable object* spell prevent damage to the target?

For instance, say a PC throws a blanket around themselves to make a "cocoon" around them and then casts *immovable object* on the blanket. Would enemies be able to damage that object (e.g. cutting through it with a weapon or setting it on fire)?

My reason for asking is this: If you rip up a fabric, it's inherently being moved. And if it can support 4000 pounds, it seems like it must have some level of invulnerability.

Comment: Is the idea that someone is arguing "I made it immovable, so it shouldn't take damage"? I don't see how the spell would otherwise interact with dealing or taking damage.

Comment: @StopBeingEvil the idea is that, if you rip up a fabric, it's inherently being moved, and if it could support 4000 pounds it must have some level of invulnerability

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate as it is has been asked before. Let us know if you think there is something substantially different about your question.

Answer (score 4):

### The object acquires no properties beyond what the spell gives it

It is the same object and can be burned, ripped, torn, cut or otherwise mutilated. As such it provides no protection to people behind it.

Comment: the idea is that ripping a fabric would by definition move it, maybe that wasn't explained well in the original question

Comment: I think this answer stands. It is clear that "magically fixed in place" means an object in its entirety cannot be moved in location. Not that each individual component molecule of the object can't be moved. That would get a bit too "real life physics" and is a rabbit hole best avoided with D&D rules! Best just to take spell descriptions at face value: They do only what they say they do and no more.